# What terms describe humorous acceptance of a compliment?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, humor

My wife complimented a chef on his delicate fish cookery last night.
Reply: "*They're great, these boil-in-the-bag dishes.*"

I complimented a violinist on his performance recently and commented that it brought tears to the eyes.
Reply: "*Was it that bad?*"

In both cases the compliment was clearly accepted.
In both cases the response was humorous.

My question is: how do we describe such humour?

It is not *sarcasm*, because there is no intention to hurt or criticize:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/banter)
> *sarcasm*:
> the use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say, made in order to hurt someone's feelings or to criticize something in a humorous way

and it is not simply *banter*, which seems too general a term:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/banter)
> *banter*:
> to talk to someone in a friendly and humorous way

Is there a better term than these?

Comment: Yes you understand my intention, with your first proposition. The question is about the *acceptance* of the compliment by the recipient . The compliments I quote are straightforward and need no special term to describe them. They could have been met simply with "Thank You" but instead they were accepted with some sort of humorous self-deprecation.

Comment: *If it's a compliment, I don't deserve it* seems to be self-effacing humor.

Comment: May be a **self-mocking acquiescence**.

Comment: The fact that an answer to another question could be **argued** to also be an answer to this one, does not make this **question** a duplicate of that one. This question seeks a word for something very specific; if one thinks that there is **nothing more specific** than *self-deprecating* that can be offered to describe it, one should post that as an answer here.

Comment: I do not accept that self-deprecating, lifted from my own explanatory comment and perhaps taken from a so-called duplicate (which is too general in its approach), is an answer to the question. It is too general a term, in the same way as I rejected *banter*. I consider the closure careless and overly dismissive of those who have been offering useful comment and answer particular to the question.

Comment: Does it need to be a single word? Would you not accept [*self-deprecating humor*](https://hbr.org/2020/07/sarcasm-self-deprecation-and-inside-jokes-a-users-guide-to-humor-at-work)?

Comment: @TinfoilHat a very appropriate notion, and acceptable in its generality. In posing the question I hoped for something a little more tightly tied to the turning of a compliment

Comment: The jury is out over whether 'no really appropriate answers' is appropriate on ELU. My view is that such answers are rarely in line with the aims of the site; they are little more than opinion/comments. //  I offered 'self-deprecating' as a  probable best fit <<_modest about or critical of oneself, especially humorously so_ ... self-deprecating jokes >> [Oxford Languages] but deleted this as I obviously believe the question has in essence been asked before. _A word for someone that deflects compliment?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of "deflection." Examples of deflecting a compliment can be found in Greek and Roman history. In Euripedes *Medea*, the title character deflects a compliment from her nurse.  In the speech "Pro Marcello," Cicero deflects a compliment on his legal skills by pointing out the skills of his opponent.

Comment: Thank you. Constructive. I shall not accept this yet because there may be other answers to come if the question is reopened.

Comment: @Anton — Isn't *deflect* the opposite of what you ask for: *accept*?

Comment: I think this is the best we shall get now. Although a deflection (a small change of direction).could be  indicative of rejection (deflection through 180 degrees)  of the compliment, I see that it is more likely to be humorous modification of acceptance a or gentle turning of the compliment.

Answer (score 4):

Both replies are attempts to make light of the situation by not accepting (the sincerity of) someone's reaction, but their origins are different:

- The first reply, "*They're great, these boil-in-the-bag dishes*", I believe is [self-deprecation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-deprecating) (or [self-depreciation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-depreciation)), out of genuine modesty or in an attempt to appear humble, probably with the intention to [add humour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation):

  > belittling or undervaluing oneself; excessively modest
- The second reply, "*was it that bad?*", is, or at least has a hint of, irony, incidentally because they likely interpreted your comment as [irony](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/irony):

  > the use of words to convey a meaning that is the opposite of its literal meaning:
  > *the irony of her reply, “How nice!” when I said I had to work all weekend*

Comment: Nice analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Several ideas come to mind, but I see the examples more as 'dad jokes' and I'm not quite sure I see how "[in] both cases the compliment was clearly accepted," so that may colour my responses (but feel free to steer me in the right direction if I'm mistaken).

Based on my interpretation, `rapartee` is what I'm hearing you describe. From [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repartee) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repartee):

> `rapartee`
>
> > 1. a. quick and witty reply
> >    b. a succession or interchange of clever retorts : amusing and usually light sparring with words
> > 2. adroitness and cleverness in reply : skill in repartee
>
> **Usage note:**  REPARTEE implies the power of answering quickly, pointedly, or wittily
>
> > 3. quick and usually funny answers and remarks in conversation:
> >
> >    *Oscar Wilde's plays are full of witty repartee*.

Other ideas along the same lines are: `quip`, `rejoinder`, `bon mot`, `witticism` ("often...ironic remark" [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/witticism)), `wisecrack` (clever or sarcastic remark).

Again, I don't see how the "compliment was accepted", but some of the other answers capture that and could be combined with words from above. For example: a self-effacing wisecrack or a self-deprecating quip.

A few other words more in the direction of "self-effacing" or generally "not serious" come to mind ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facetious)):

> `facetious`
>
> not serious about a serious subject, in an attempt to be funny or to appear clever
>
> **Usage note:** Some common synonyms of facetious are humorous, jocose, jocular, [waggish], and witty. While all these words mean "provoking or intended to provoke laughter," facetious stresses a desire to produce laughter...ill-timed attempts at wit or humor

Sardonicism tends to be but is [not necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardonicism) dark/malicious, that is clever and playful, while also not being overly broad.

Here's a definition and example from the same [site](https://literaryterms.net/sardonic/):

> `Sardonic`
>
> Sardonic is an adjective describing dry, understated, and sort of mocking speech or writing—such as a clever remark that stings because it’s so accurate. While sardonic comments seem slightly hostile, they are supposed to be witty and humorous rather than deeply hurtful.
>
> *I did not attend the funeral, but I sent a letter saying I approved of it. (Mark Twain)*

Comment: Thank you for a deal of relevant contextual thought.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a witty remark or a witty retort.

> [witty]: The adjective witty can be used to describe those quick
> little funny remarks that often demonstrate a sharp, biting humor
> delivered in a playful manner.

> [retort]:
> a quick answer that is angry or funny

Comment: Thank you. I agree that the response is witty, although the term is very general and not tightly focussed on the turning of a compliment. On a minor point, the site encourages us to give references for our material; in this case others (such as non-native English speakers) might appreciate a dictionary reference for the words you mention.

Answer (score 0):

"False modesty" works, unless you feel that something false must always be bad.